# Exclude nested fields in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

is it possible to exclude fields of nested Documents in Spring Data MongoDB?.

If tried it with

```
query.fields().exclude("user.password");
```

but that ends with the hole user document be excluded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve that using [Aggregation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html) and [ProjectOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ProjectionOperation.html).

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project().andExclude("user.password"); 
mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(projectionOperation);
```